# extract float number after specific character

Tags: python, list, file, int

There is my problem, I want to get all flat numbers after sign equal but I dont get how to it.
All my numbers are on a file and I put this file on a list in python, so I want to get numbers after equal sign.
exemple : "average frame rate = 22.5566"
I want the 22.5566 float numbers.
Thanks for your help.

This is for a script that will calculate the average of the frame rate value on a file .txt

I tried this :

```
l = []

with open("floatnumber.txt", 'r') as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for row in csv_f:
        l.append(log(float(row[1])))

print (l)
```

but doesnt work

i got nothing ..

there is an piece of my .txt file:

```
AnimatonPath completed in 0.0455575 seconds, completing 1 frames,
             average frame rate = 21.9503
AnimatonPath completed in 0.0691637 seconds, completing 1 frames,
             average frame rate = 14.4585'
```

and i only want the float numbers after the equal sign

Comment: Please post a few lines from your txt file and the expected result

Comment: Post a piece of your file `floatnumber.txt`, so people can see how it's formatted.

Comment: its done friend

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regex which might be a more robust way of solving the problem

```py
with open("floatnumber.txt", 'r') as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for row in csv_f:
        results = re.findall("=\s*?(\d+\.\d+|\d+)", row[2])
        l.append(log(float(results[0])))
    print (l)
```

Don't forget to use

```py
import re
```

Comment: i tried ur code and i get this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/skehal/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/testfloat.py", line 16, in <module>
    results = re.findall("=\s*?(\d+\.\d+|\d+)", row)
  File "C:\Users\skehal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line 223, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I guess row is a list, try with passing row[1] like in your question, see the updated answer,
based on the snippted of your txt it should probably be row[2]

Answer (score 0):

Use split()

```
l = []

with open("floatnumber.txt", 'r') as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for row in csv_f:
        l.append(row.split('= ')[1])

print (l)
```

This will take the second argument in the split, in other words whatever is behind the equals sign. You might want to remove a new line as well:

```
for row in csv_f:
        l.append(row.split('= ')[1].strip('\n')
```